# PHP get amount of logs stored in a row

Tags: php

I am sorry if my title is causing confusion, but I don't know how to explain better in such short amount of space, so I'll try here:
I have a table that stores logs, it has this structure:

```
log_id, username, action, ip, date
```

The "action" is for example `changed password` or something similar.
If I have 4 logs in a row that is for the same user and the same action, I don't want to display it four times. I only want to display like this:
`PHPDeveloper: Changed password (4)`
I tried doing this myself but I couldn't really figure it out, I think I just need to structure my array better and overwrite the old values for the same log.
Currently, my code displays:
`PHPDeveloper: Changed password (1)`
`PHPDeveloper: Changed password (2)`
`PHPDeveloper: Changed password (3)`
`PHPDeveloper: Changed password (4)`

My code:

```
<?php

    include("../inc/classes.php");
    if(!DB::isLoggedIn()) {
        header("Location: ../");
        exit;
    } else if(DB::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id", array(":id" => DB::isLoggedIn()))[0]['username'] != "Chrille332") {
        header("Location: ../");
        exit;
    }

    $view_logs = array();

    $logs = DB::query("SELECT * FROM logs");
    for($i = 0; $i < count($logs); $i++) {
        $encountered = 0;

        // Check if the log has been encountered before, and check until you find something else
        $view_logs[$i] = "<li>".$logs[$i]['account_name']." ".$logs[$i]['action']."</li>";
        for($j = 1; $j < $i+1; $j++) {
            $encountered++;
            if(($view_logs[$i]['username'] && $view_logs[$i]['action'])==($view_logs[$j]['username'] && $view_logs[$j]['action'])) {
                $view_logs[$i] = "<li>".$logs[$i]['account_name']." ".$logs[$i]['action']." (".$encountered.")</li>";
            } else {
                $view_logs[$i] = "<li>".$logs[$i]['account_name']." ".$logs[$i]['action']."</li>";
            }
        }

    }

    // $view_logs[$i] = "<li>".$logs[$i]['account_name']." ".$logs[$i]['action']." (".$encountered.")</li>";
    // $view_logs[$i] = "<li>".$logs[$i]['account_name']." ".$logs[$i]['action']."</li>";



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        var_dump($view_logs);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you might not be allowed to save the users IP address without consent, even in Sweden you now must conform to the GDPR (European Law). You further do not have an imprint on your website! Please respect the users privacy.

Comment: It not officially released, but thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Wait, how do you know I'm from Sweden?

Comment: I have been visiting your website through your Stackoverflow profile and read your Terms of Service ;-) You set your location also in your Stackoverflow profile.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a group by on your SQL:

```
SELECT username, action, COUNT(*) total FROM users WHERE id=:id GROUP BY username, action
```

With the above query you will get all info you need for your display

Comment: This will also group non-consecutive items.

Comment: Not sure if this works yet, I'm busy atm but I'll be sure to try it and mark as working if it works, thank you sir!